# OBDSIM gui plugin on windows

Tags: android, obd-ii

i am trying to develope an application on android that connects to ELM372 and using obdsim to simulate it the problem is whenever i do this
 `obdsim.exe -g gui_fltk`
 i get `Couldn't find generator "gui_fltk"`
and it is not present in the list `obdsim.exe -l`

i am using obdsim for window (exe)
i think it is better to use it with cygwin but i have absolutely no idea how to do it as i have very little knowledge in linux

so, i need help 
a)setting up the gui plugin 
or 
b)a guide on how to use it with cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have a package that is required to build the .exe? Missing some information here, did you build it yourself, or did you download an .exe?

Anyway, with cygwin -->

http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/

Scroll to the 'building on windows' paragraph for some more information and you can always mail the creator of this piece of software. I recently did and got an answer!